# Data Extraction of values based on different column and complicated data manipulation based on different column

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

need to extract the values from the data frame provided below

I have a code

```
r<-showWaterfall(xgb, explainer, k1, X_test,1, type = "binary")
```

out put of the below code is
[image]

I need to extract x column **based on y values**, such that based on the top 5 maximum value, I need to extract the x value such that I need only the column name and nothing else

for example I need  **Change_LTV only** and not Change_LTV = -0.633700109225944 if it's corresponding Y value is in **top 5 max value of Y**

Once I have that then I need to run the again  the waterfall code and repeat the same process for another **input numeric value which is 9**

```
r<-showWaterfall(xgb, explainer, k1, X_test,9, type = "binary")
```

These numeric i/p value will change and would be random in the above case now it's **9** , the input value will keep on changing for more than 1000+ and I need to store all the result from different input in one data frame

**Final Output**
[image]

**The above output is just for understanding purpose ,How I need the o/p it is just an example**

I need to change the value from 1 to 9,100,25 ... and so on and stack all the results in one data frame as shown in output

need to iterate the same code

```
r<-showWaterfall(xgb, explainer, k1, X_test,9, type = "binary")
```

for different input value which will change

I tried this approach but not getting the results in the desired format

```
count_test<-c(1,9,100,22,45)
for (i in count_test)
{ 
  r<-showWaterfall(xgb, explainer, k1, X_test,i, type = "binary")
  
  k<-as.data.frame(r$data)
  k$index<-i
  datalist[[i]] <- k
}
datalist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea. I ordered the output by `y` (absolut highest value on top), took the first five `x` and cleaned the names. The `count_test` value and the names from `x` are written in a predefined dataframe (`df`).

Therefore the result might be organised like in your output image.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Inpuvalue = NA, 
                 Attribut1 = NA, 
                 Attribut2 = NA,
                 Attribut3 = NA,
                 Attribut4 = NA,
                 Attribut5 = NA)

count_test<-c(1,9,100,22,45)
for (i in count_test)
{ 
  r<-showWaterfall(xgb, explainer, k1, X_test, i, type = "binary")
  
  attribut <-as.data.frame(r$data) %>%
    arrange(desc(y)) %>% 
    filter(x != "intercept") %>%
    slice(1:5) %>% 
    pull(x) %>%
    str_remove(., "\\s=.*")
  
  df[which(i == count_test), ] <- c(i, attribut)  

}

´´´
```

Comment: I am removing abs value as I need the max value  and also removing intercept which is the 1st row by below logic , However still getting intercept as column.

attribut <-as.data.frame(r$data) %>% .[-1,] %>%
    arrange(desc((y))) %>%


I want to remove the intercept column and then the logic should work not sure what I am doing wrong could you help

Comment: There are two intercepts in the r$data. The first one in row 1 and the second in row 50. I'll try to remove them both, give me a moment.

Comment: I filtered the intercepts and removed the unnecessary abs(). Does ist work now?

Comment: Thnks, is there any way to keep only distinct attributes for example I am getting for  same attribute name twice like vintage for attribute 4 and attribute 5 can we have something like distinct so as to keep top 5 attributes which are distinct

Comment: I think something is odd with your structur code above or/and as.data.frame(r$data). Every value in y exists twice in the dataset. And every factor gets two different values.  For me its unclear which y is the true value for x. Just removing one value of y for each x doesn't seem correct. Probably this will remove the correct value and your results will be wrong. You need to find out, why r$data douples its y values and which value is the correct value for each x. Unfortenetly I can't run the code of showWaterfall(). So can't help you with this step.

Comment: I guess as.data.frame(r$data) is not the best way to get the values/Importance?.